# Ember - Bind fail when transition back to login view

Tags: ember.js, authentication

When i first go the my login url, the inputs are correctly binded to the properties on my controller.

Then a press logout and what it does is transition back to the login page.

When i try to login again, it fails, because the input values arent binded to the controller, additionally i get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Attempted to register a view with an id already in use: login
```

If i refresh the page it works.

Some of my code for references:

**LoginRoute**

```
export
default Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.reset();
    },

    beforeModel: function() {
        if (!Ember.isEmpty(this.controllerFor('sessions.login').get('token'))) {
            this.transitionTo('promotions');
        }
    }
});
```

**LogoutRoute**

```
export
default Ember.Route.extend({    
    beforeModel: function() {
        this.controllerFor('sessions.login').reset();
        this.transitionTo('sessions.login');
    }
});
```

**LoginAction on Controller**

```
    loginUser: function() {
        var _this = this;

        var login = this.get("login");
        var pass = this.get("password");
```

**Login Form**

```
<form role="form" {{action 'loginUser' on='submit'}}>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" placeholder="Login" value=login autofocus="autofocus"}}
                    {{input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" value=password}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ><span>Entrar</span></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

After testing some more, i saw that the textFields are duplicating when i transition back to this page.

I really can't figure out, why

Comment: I found the problem.

My login page was hidden on application.hbs, so ember got lost when i redirect back to it.

I createad a view and set the template for it, now its ok.

Comment: Put it in an answer and accept it ^^